# Model.findById is returning undefined when I use mongoose .populate.exec methods

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate my `Question` model with its answers and find the community using its id as shown:

```
router.get('/communities/:type/:id_community/:id_question' , (req , res)=>{
    console.log(req.params.id_question);
    PublicCommunity.findById(req.params.id_community , (err , foundCommunity)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.redirect('back');
        }else{
            Question.findById(req.params.id_question).populate('answers').exec ((err2 , foundQuestion)=>{
                console.log(foundQuestion);
                seedAnswer(foundQuestion);
                if(err2){
                    console.log('err here');
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect('back');
                }else{

                    res.render('../views/publicCommunity/questions/show' , {type:req.params.type  ,question: foundQuestion , community: foundCommunity});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Question schema is:

```
let questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    title: String,
    text : String,
    comments:[{
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref  : 'Comment'
    }],
    answers: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Answer'
    }],
    date: {type: Date , default: Date.now},
    author: String
});
```

When I `console.log(foundQuestion)`, it returns undefined. When I don't populate the `Question` model, it works fine and the `foundQuestion` has the required value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. There was a spelling error in the collection name. Thus the `answers` collection was not being populated and was returning `null`. After changing the collection's name, everything is working fine.